# JS: Comparing Arrays and adding new items or removing items no longer in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

When I query my DB for items i generate an array say a list like

```
 ArrayOne =  [Apple, Banana, Orange, Banana] 
//yes, an item can be there twice or more
```

then I duplicate it in a `ArrayOne_Copy = ArrayOne`

ok, 
then after an interval of 5 minutes I check again the DB and generate and replace the array `ArrayOne` say now is like

```
 ArrayOne =  [Apple, Peach, Banana, Pineapple, Banana, Melon]
```

at this point I want to compare the `ArrayOne_Copy` with the newly generated `ArrayOne` and rebuild the list from the new list but without clearing the list and generating a new output, but i want to only add the new items or remove the one no longer in the list

if I can "speak" code I would tell the script to:

```
Don't touch `Apple` because has not changed
Push 'Peach" between `Apple` and `Banana`
Push `Pineapple` between `Banana` and `Banana`
Remove `Orange`
Add `Melon`
```

so. I'm kinda lost, and maybe the solution is very simple.
Can you suggest the best practice?

Comment: Hmm. Have you given thought to a Levenshtein-style algorithm? Set the elements on an NxM grid and walk through it with specific rules?

Comment: Regardless of whether you use Levenshtein or not, you need some sort of diff algorithm here, to determine insertions and deletions of specific elements.

Comment: no idea who Levenshtein is, i'ma  self taught developer, but i'd love to know more about it

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Answer (score 1):

**You're not duplicating it, you're referencing it.**

You will need to make a hard copy of the array which can be done using `slice()`.

```
var ArrayOne_Copy = ArrayOne.slice(0);
```

---

For example:

```
var ArrayOne = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Banana'];

var ArrayOne_Copy = ArrayOne.slice(0);

ArrayOne.push('Melon');

console.log(ArrayOne);
console.log(ArrayOne_Copy);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y7czyn3h/

http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-clone-array

Answer (score -1):

You can use this kind of function:

```
Array.prototype.complete = function( arr ){
  var result = new Array();
  for( var a in arr )
    result[ a ] = this[ a ] ? this[ a ] : arr[ a ];
  return result;
}
```

Like this :

```
ArrayFull = ArrayOne_Copy.complete( ArrayOne );
```

Then `ArrayFull` will be the array modified with .